# Use two different custom tableview cells in same tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using one type of Custom Table View Cell, but when other data is posted to my Table View, I want it to be displayed in a different Custom Table View Cell in the same table.

For example, I've created a chat in my Table View. However when certain details are posted, I want a separate cell design to display these details. See my code below so far.

**My question:** How can I write, "If field_swaptime in self.messages is empty, display ChatTableViewCell - if it contains data, display SwapDetailTableViewCell" ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";
    static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";

    NSDictionary *data = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    if ( [data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"] == nil )  {

     NSLog(@"THIS IS DATA %@", data);


        ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }



        NSString *userName = [data objectForKey:@"name"];
        [cell.sendingUser setText:userName];

        NSString *messageBody = [data objectForKey:@"body"];
        [cell.messageDisplayed setText:messageBody];

        NSString *timeReceived = [data objectForKey:@"published at"];
        NSLog(@"Message Received at %@", timeReceived);
        [cell.timeStamp setText:timeReceived];




        return cell;
    }

    else {


        SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SwapDetailTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        }

        NSString *Time = [data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"];
        NSLog(@"This is time %@", Time);
        [cell.startTime setText:Time];

        NSString *TimeEnd = [data objectForKey:@"field_endswaptime"];
        [cell.endTime setText:TimeEnd];


                return cell;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically looking to write your initial `if` as:

```
NSDictionary *data = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//
// if self.messages is nil, then data will be nil and we'll display
// a ChatTableViewCell as before. If data is valid, but there is no
// value associated with "field_swaptime", then again, we'll display
// a ChatTableViewCell. However, if self.messages IS valid and 
// there IS a value associated with "field_swaptime" key, then the
// if clause fails, and we execute the else and return a
// SwapDetailTableViewCell.
//
if ( !data || ![data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"] } {
    ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSString *userName = [data objectForKey:@"name"];
    [cell.sendingUser setText:userName];

    NSString *messageBody = [data objectForKey:@"body"];
    [cell.messageDisplayed setText:messageBody];

    NSString *timeReceived = [data objectForKey:@"published at"];
    NSLog(@"Message Received at %@", timeReceived);
    [cell.timeStamp setText:timeReceived];


    return cell;
}
else {
    SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SwapDetailTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    NSString *Time = [data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"];
    [cell.startTime setText:Time];

    NSString *TimeEnd = [data objectForKey:@"field_endswaptime"];
    [cell.endTime setText:TimeEnd];

    return cell;
}
```

Bonus: if `self.messages` is valid, and `data` is valid, then you already have `data` and don't need to multiple calls to `[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`. (you *should* do a bounds sanity check on `self.messages.count` against `indexPath.row` before calling `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row`, but the defensive coding part is up to you to put together)

Objective C is pretty nifty in that calling a method on nil object, just returns nil. So, it is perfectly valid to ignore whether `self.messages` is valid or not, and just retrieve the data it contains. If it is valid (and your index is in bounds of the array), then a valid `NSDictionary` will be returned that you can use throughout the `if/else` clause.

Comment: Ok 1 - You rock for posting this answer. Ha ha. 2) Can you explain what this line means: if(!data || ![data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"]) { E.g. is it - "If field_swaptime in self.messages is <null>, ChatTableViewCell is displayed"? I implemented your code, and it seems to use ChatTableViewCell even after data posts to field_swaptime? The table should add ChatTableViewCell if data is posted without field_swaptime, and use SwapDetailTableViewCell if field_swaptime is present (thus, I should see two diff cell designs in my table)?

Comment: E.g. I don't want the entire table using the SAME cell - I should have a table that shows two different cell designs, no?

Comment: Yes, correct. the if is saying "if there is no data dictionary (because self.messages was nil), or there is no value associated with "field_swaptime" key, then display a ChatTableViewCell, else display a SwapDetailTableViewCell"

Comment: Ok, so self.messages will never be entirely nil (because other fields exist in self.messages), but field_swaptime will be nil sometimes (my console returns field_swaptime as <null>, I imagine this is the same as nil). For some reason, even when this field is nil, my table is only using one cell? To boot, when it uses SwapDetailTableViewCell, the data isn't populating in the labels (it's saying the code I use to retrieve Time string and TimeEnd string is null)?

Comment: Your original code checked that self.messages was nil or not, so that means the `if` portion clause was destined to always fail anyhow. Given that, the check for `!data` is apparently superfluous, but `![data objectForKey:@"..."]` is still valid. As for the rest, sounds like time to break out the debugger.

Comment: Lol sorted that one - pulled out the debugger! Found it. That said, I still can't get two separate cells to show up in the same tableview :/ Doesn't this line: if ( !data || ![data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"]  just check to see if field_swaptime is nil or not? That said, even when I change that line to something like:   if([data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"] == 0) { I still get one cell for all posts in the tableview.

Comment: `if (![data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"]) {` checks if the *value* returned from the call is `nil`, yes. The equivalent is roughly `if ( [data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"] == nil ) {` or `if ([data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"] == 0 ) {`. But, yes, you can show more than one flavor of table view cell in a table at the same time. Heck, every one of them can be unique in layout, for that matter.

Comment: Ok, do me a solid, ha ha. See my edited answer above (where I've implemented your code). For some bizarre reason, my entire table is still only using ChatTableViewCell - even when data is present in field_swaptime. Do you see something wrong in my edit that could be causing this? Cheers, and btw, you've been awesome.

Comment: Sounds like none of your dictionaries (data model) contain a value associated with @"field_swaptime". Better check your data model.

Answer (score 0):

The type of cell you get is determined by the type you register to correspond with the identifier.  So, when you're setting up the table (say, in `viewDidLoad`)...

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ChatTableViewCell" bundle:nil];  // bundle:nil means main bundle
[self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ChatTableIdentifier"];

UINib *nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"OtherTableViewCell" bundle:nil];  
[self.tableView registerNib:nib2 forCellReuseIdentifier:@"OtherIdentifier"];
```

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you use the modern dequeue method, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, which never returns nil and always returns an instance built from the nib you registered earlier...

```
// generically
NSString *identifier = (/*some condition*/)? @"ChatTableIdentifier" : @"OtherIdentifier";

// or alternatively, given the condition in your comment...
NSString *identifier = (!data[@"field_swaptime"])? @"ChatTableIdentifier" : @"OtherIdentifier";


UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// now cell is one of your two custom classes, built from their respective nibs.
```

Based on the same condition, you can cast `cell` to either kind, and configure it...

```
if (/*same condition as identifier*/) {
    ChatTableViewCell *chatCell = (ChatTableViewCell *)cell;
    // do your config for this type here
} else {
    OtherTableViewCell *otherTypeCell = (OtherTableViewCell *)cell;
    // do your config for this other type here
}
return cell;
```

Comment: This line: NSString *identifier = (/*some condition*/)? @"ChatTableIdentifier" : @"OtherIdentifier"; is giving me grief? E.g. My condition is: if(!data || ![data objectForKey:@"field_swaptime"]) , however putting that in the line stated says it's still expecting some sort of expression?

Comment: I think that's just ternary operator syntax that's tripping you up.  Please see edit, replacing the commented with  `// generically ` with the one commented as  `// alternatively ...`

Comment: Implemented the above - it seems like it should work, and yet I'm still only getting one cell type (even when field_swaptime isn't null)!

Comment: Be sure you're correctly determining the type by saying `po cell` in the debugger.  If it really is the same type for different identifiers, then it must be that the two different nibs that you registered contain the same type.